# CSV file input and sorted output is formmated incorrectly

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I am just trying to learn python and I am working on a program to take in information from a csv file sort it then output it into a new csv file. my problem is that in the output, the data ends up being in one row instead of the original 5 rows. I am not sure why, I am attempting to open the new sorted file in LibreOffice Calc and the formatting is off, does this have something to do with the delimiters? Thanks

```
import csv
import operator

name = raw_input()

myfile = name
o = open(myfile, 'rU')
mydata = csv.reader(o)


sortedlist = sorted(mydata, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for row in sortedlist:
print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])

o.close()

print('Enter the name for the output file')
ofile = raw_input()

with open(ofile, 'wb') as csvfile:
sortwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
sortwriter.writerow(sortedlist)
```

Comment: csvwriter writes by row.  So if you send a single list to sortwriter.writerow(), it will print to a single line.  If you want to write out to multiple rows, you will need a list of lists. [[row1 data], [row2 data], [row3 data]] and you will need to iterate the outer list.  Also, the code as given above won't work because python requires proper indentation.

Comment: Change `writerow()` to `writerows()`, singular to plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow()` writes a single row at a time.  Since you want to write them all at once so you need to call its plural cousin `writerows()`.

I have taken the liberty of cleaning up your code:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

fin_name = raw_input('Enter the name for the input file')
fout_name = raw_input('Enter the name for the output file')

with open(fin_name, 'rb') as fin: # switched filemode from 'rU'. change if really needed
    with open(fout_name 'wb') as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        rows = sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        writer.writerows(rows) # changed writerow to writerows
```